# replace a fixed position in a file with a set string

Tags: parsing, sed, cut

Hello I am looking to do the following:

`file= sample.out`

replace whatever text is in position `10-15` with `"77777"` but only on rows that start with `ABC`

so far I have:

```
cat sample.out | sed -r 's/^ABC(.{9})/\177777/'
```

But `ABC` at the beginning of the lines gets removed and `77777` gets inserted into the text position instead of replacing the existing the characters in that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without example I use this.

File: `repl.txt`

```
0000000001111111111222222222233333333333
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
ABCDEFGH<12345>IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ======:
```

With this command:

```sh
$ sed -e 's/^\(ABC.\{6\}\).\{5\}\(.*\)$/\177777\2/' repl.txt
0000000001111111111222222222233333333333
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
ABCDEFGH<77777>IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ======:
```

Comment: Just for some readability to Arnaud Valmary  answer I will add the -r or -E to remove the escape characters:
sed -r 's/^(ABC.{6}).{5}(.*)$/\177777\2/' file.txt
Anything that is under ( ) are your capture groups and you refer to it as \1 or \2

Comment: thank you that worked and thanks PraveenB for further explanation which helped me understand

Answer (score 2):

Please try following `awk` program, using samples from @Arnaud's post.

```
awk -v newVal="77777" '/^ABC/{print substr($0,1,9) newVal substr($0,16);next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `awk` program here. Firstly creating an `awk` variable named `newVal` which has `77777` value in it. In main program checking if line starts from ABC then printing sub strings(printing everything apart from 10th to 15th position in current line, printing new value in its place). If condition is not met(ie: line doesn't start from ABC) then print that line simply.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^ABC/{s/./&\n/14;T;s//\n&/10;s/\n.*\n/77777/}' file
```

Pattern match on `ABC` at the start of a line, delimit characters 10-14 (5 characters) by newlines and replace them and the characters between by a replacement string.

N.B. The delimiters used must be unique (newlines cannot be a part of any pattern space because newlines are used by sed to define the pattern space). Also delimiters must be inserted from largest to smallest as the newline(s) would upset the counting from the start of the line.

---

To overwrite from a specific position, use:

```
sed -E '/^ABC/{s/./\n&/10;T;s/$/\n77777/;:a;s/\n.(.*\n)(.)/\2\n\1/;ta;s/\n//g}' file
```

---

An alternative:

```
sed -E 's/^(ABC.{6}).{5}/\177777/' file
```